The availability Interim Measures before the CJEU
I read this part of a book about interim measures from the CJEU (Court of Justice of the European Union), and I am not sure if I completely understand it or not.
Does it mean that if the financial loss cannot be fixed or compensated for, it is considered serious, and the court may grant interim measures to address it? Conversely, if the loss can be compensated for later, the court may not see it as necessary to grant interim measures.
Part of the book:

Provisional legal protection (Articles 278 and 279 TFEU) Actions filed
with the Court of Justice or the General Court, or appeals lodged
against their judgments, do not have suspensive effect. It is,
however, possible to apply to the Court of Justice or the General
Court for an order to suspend the application of the contested act
(Article 278 TFEU) or for an interim court order (Article 279 TFEU).
The merits of any application for interim measures are assessed by the
courts on the basis of the following three criteria. Prospect of
success on the main issue (fumus boni juris). This is assessed by the
court in a preliminary summary examination of the arguments submitted
by the appellant. Urgency of the order. This is assessed on the basis
of whether the order applied for by the appellant is necessary in
order to ward off serious and irreparable harm. The criteria used for
making this assessment include the nature and seriousness of the
infringement, and its specific and irreversibly adverse effects on the
appellant’s property and other objects of legal protection. Financial
loss is deemed to be of a serious and irreparable nature only if it
cannot be made good even if the appellant is successful in the main
proceedings. Weighing of interests. The adverse effects likely to be
suffered by the appellant if the application for an interim order is
refused are weighed against the EU’s interest in immediate
implementation of the measure, and against the detrimental effects on
third parties if the interim order were to be issued.


This is the standard rule of interim injunctions
The courts will only issue them if the harm that arises is irreparable by money. Typically, that means there must be a real danger to human life or health, the environment, or to an irreplaceable material object (such as an archaeological site, or unique artefact).
If the damage caused would be compensable with money, and the defendant has that much money, the activity will be allowed to continue while the case runs its course.
